# Form timing out with drupal_set_message

Tags: 7, forms

I am getting some type of timing out error and not sure how to fix it or even where to begin, the error looks something like this http://pastebin.com/M8Wz4KEY

```
/** 
 * Block info 
 */ 

function zillow_block_info(){
    $blocks['zillow_block'] = array(
        'info' => t('Zillow Block'),
    );
    return $blocks;
}

function zillow_block_view($delta = ''){
    $block = array();
        switch ($delta){
    case 'zillow_block';
        $block['subject'] = t('Zillow Block');
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('zillow_form');
    break;
    }
    return $block;
}

/**
 * Form Info
 */

function zillow_form($form, &$zinfo){

    $form['description'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#title' => t('Get your mortgage rates'),
    );
    $form['rates'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Mortgage Rates'),
        '#collapsiable' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );

    $form['rates']['state'] = array(
        '#type' => ('select'),
        '#title' => t('Choose One'),
        '#options' => array( 
            'CA' => t('California'),  
        ),
        '#required' => TRUE

    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
    );
    return $form;
}

/**
 * Api info 
 */

function zillow_api_info($form, &$zinfo){
    $state_value = $zinfo['values']['state'];
    $zillow_id = 'Xx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx';
    $xml = file_get_contents('http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetRateSummary.htm?zws-id='.$zillow_id.'&'.$state_value.'');

    foreach($xml->response->today->rate as $todays_rates){
        print $todays_rates;
        '</br>';
    }

    foreach($xml->response->lastWeek->rate as $lastWeeks_rates){
        print $lastWeeks_rates;
        '</br>';
    }

    return zillow_api_info();
}   

/**
 * Submit Info  
 */

function zillow_form_submit($form, &$zinfo){
        drupal_set_message(t('this is the info the form has submitted. zip=@zipcode, states=@states, todaysrates=@todaysrates',
        array('@states' => $zinfo['values']['state'], '@todaysrates' => zillow_api_info())));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an infinite loop in your code...

The function `zillow_api_info()` returns a call to itself, which will result in an infinite recursion from which PHP can't escape. As you're calling this function during the call to `drupal_set_message()` I'd guess that's why you're getting the timeout.

FYI You're not passing the `@zipcode` replacement to the `t()` function, it shouldn't cause an error but it might be a bug :)

Comment: im not entirely sure thats the reason, when I try to print out just the function itself it returns once, and doesnt loop again. In your opinion what should I change that makes you think its in a infinity loop?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what your function is trying to do so I can't really comment on what the code *should* be...but trust me, you 1000% definitely have an infinite recursion in your function at the moment. Step through the code in that function and ask yourself "at what point does this function return to the place it was originally called?". The answer is never :) Recursive functions are very common but you **have** to have a method for escaping from the loop. Currently you don't have such a method in place

Comment: =) thanks I ended up taking the return; off, you were right

Comment: No worries glad to help :)